# Searching for right double angle quotes on freebsd7 unix

Tags: grep, freebsd

I know how to search for a string in files using grep

```
grep -Flr --include "*" 'string' files/
```

However how would I search for right double angle quotes ( » ) as the character will not appear in the terminal.

Comment: do you mean it doesn't appear when you type out the command ?

Answer (score 0):

The double angle quotes are ASCII codes 174 (<<) and 175 (>>), if you are talking about ANSI character set and not Unicode.

You can try

```sh
grep `echo "\256"` file
```

256 is the octal ASCII value for <<. Note that octal value is enclosed in **backquotes**.